# MPI sporadic errors

Tags: c, mpi

I'm running MPI code that looks like this (see below for explanation):

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

...

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int i,j,local_N,num_procs = 0;
    int N = 16; // width and height of matrix

    int rank;
    float ** A;
    float ** local_A;

    // MPI stuff
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &num_procs); // "size" is number of processes
    MPI_Status status;

    // allocate and initialize A
    if (rank == 0) {
        A = allocate_matrix(N, N);
        initialize_matrix(A, N, N);
    }

    // allocate local matrices
    local_N = N / num_procs;
    local_A = allocate_matrix(local_N, N);

    //send/rcv pieces of matrix
    for (i = 1; i < num_procs; i++) {
        if (rank == 0) {
            MPI_Send(A[i * local_N], N, MPI_FLOAT, i, 123, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }

        if (rank == i) {
            MPI_Recv(local_A[0], N, MPI_FLOAT, 0, 123, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        }
    }

    if (rank == 0) free_matrix(A, N, N);
    free_matrix(local_A, local_N, N);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

and here are those helper methods:

```
float ** allocate_matrix(int rows, int cols) {
    int i = 0;
    float ** matrix = (float **) malloc(rows * sizeof(float *));

    for (i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
        matrix[i] = (float *) malloc(cols * sizeof(float));
    }

    return matrix;
}

void initialize_matrix(float ** matrix, int rows, int cols) {
    int i, j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = ((float)(rand()%10000))/1000.0;
        }
    }
}

void free_matrix(float ** matrix, int rows, int cols) {
    int i, j = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < rows; j++) free(matrix[j]);
}
```

Basically, I'm splitting up a 16 by 16 matrix into (number of processes) chunks and sending one row from each chunk to each process. Printing the rows before and after the send and receive shows that they are being sent properly.

I've run this code over and over using `mpirun -n 4 ./<name of executable>`, and each time, something different happens. Either:

- normal exit
- `mpirun noticed that process rank ... exited on signal 6`
- `mpirun noticed that process rank ... exited on signal 10`
- `mpirun noticed that process rank ... exited on signal 11`

I saw the signal 6 and thought "double free()!", but I've tried removing the freeing methods, and the signal 6's persist, along with the other errors. Any idea why these errors are occurring, and why it's a different error each time? The debugger trace makes it look like the problem is happening in `MPI_Finalize()`.

Comment: Why are you sending just one element? 
MPI_Send(A[i * local_N], 1, MPI_FLOAT, i, 123, MPI_COMM_WORLD); Shouldn't 'count = n_local' instead of 1?

Comment: Ah good catch, but that was just during debugging. Sending N elements it bugs out as well. Editing now.

Comment: Put MPI_Init() at the very beginning. It's not recommended to do anything before MPI_Init() and after MPI_Finalize(). Have a look here: http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_Init.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an MPI problem. The error comes from the allocation function. You're iterating over the number of columns instead of the number of rows.

```
for (i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
```

should be

```
for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
```

to match the malloc above. You were mallocing 4 rows, but iterating over 16 columns.